# Convert into secure PDO statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, sql-injection

Could someone show me how I would go about converting my current `UPDATE tablename SET column` into a safe and secure statement using PDO to protect against SQL injection ? I am trying to better understand binding and PDO but am having trouble with setting it up with PDO.  Here is what I currently have with regular msqli

```
<?php

session_start();
$db = mysqli_connect("hostname", "username", "password", "dbname"); 
$username = $_SESSION['jigowatt']['username'];
mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE login_users SET Points=Points+15 WHERE username='$username'");


?>
```

Comment: you can also secure using procedural way..

Comment: You can adapt the very first example in the manual page (or example #3): http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Assuming that usernames are alpha-numeric, and that you are putting the username into the session and that it isn't some kind of user input, there is no opportunity for injection here.

Comment: Look at http://bobby-tables.com/php.html for examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### MySQL

You don't need PDO or MySQLi for that. [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string) protect you against sql injection:

```
$name = 'Bob';
$age = 25;
$description = "' OR 1=1"; // a SQL injection string

$query = "
UPDATE people(name, age, description) 
VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."', ".(int) $age.", '".mysql_real_escape_string($description)."');";

// a secure query execution
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

### PDO

#### With `PDO::quote()`

`PDO::quote()` is equal to `mysql_real_escape_string`:

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);

$name = 'Bob';
$age = 25;
$description = "' OR 1=1"; // a SQL injection string

$query = "
UPDATE people(name, age, description) 
VALUES (".$pdo->quote($name).", ".(int) $age.", ".$pdo->quote($description).");";

// a secure query execution
$result = $pdo->query($query);
```

#### With prepared statements

You can use prepared statements. You could put the hole query inside the prepared statement, but it is better to use placeholders for variables:

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);

$name = 'Bob';
$age = 25;
$description = "' OR 1=1"; // a SQL injection string

$query = "
UPDATE people(name, age, description) 
VALUES (:name, :age, :description);";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query); // prepare the query

// execute the secure query with the parameters
$result = $pdo->execute(array(
    ':name' => $name,
    ':age' => $age,
    ':description' => $description,
));
```

Comment: Should be `$stmt->execute` not `$pdo->execute`, I think